# AndroidScript - DrawArc equivalent?

Tags: javascript, android, android-canvas, draw, android-scripting

I'm trying to draw an Arc in AndroidScript on the canvas. Does that method exist?

Thanks,

Dan

[they're making me add more to the question, so here you go]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good answer posted by Schnee Wittchen on another forum:-

You may use the DrawArc method of the image object. I found it a little bit tricky as it behaves different to the normal explanation, but anyway it is usable.

Syntax:    img.DrawArc( x1, y1, x2, y2 ,startangle, sweepangle );

With the x1, y1, x2, y2 you define a rectangle. Within this rectangle the arc is drawn, starting at the startangle and turning clockwise by the sweepangle.